Can I dynamically add a test file in mochajs in browser?
In the documentation I see a connection option.
It adds a script to the html page.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Mocha Tests</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.js"></script>

    <script class="mocha-init">
      mocha.setup('bdd');
      mocha.checkLeaks();
    </script>
    <script src="test.array.js"></script>
    <script src="test.object.js"></script>
    <script src="test.xhr.js"></script>
    <script class="mocha-exec">
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

I need to load a test from a blob.
import { mocha } from 'mocha'

mocha.setup({
   asyncOnly: false,
   ui: 'bdd'
});

const urlTEst = new URL(path, import.meta.url);

let test = await fetch(urlTEst.pathname)
test = await test.blob()
let objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(test);

mocha.addFile(objectURL);
or
mocha.addFile(test);
mocha.checkLeaks()
mocha.run()

I need this so that I can delete uploaded files, add new ones and run tests with new files.
When adding a script to the page again, it does not load as a test
When I try to use the addFile method I get an error
if blob
 Arguments to path.resolve must be strings

or file
Could not dynamically require

How to add tests in the browser dynamically?
And how can they be reloaded on new ones?
